# How to create 10bit H.265 or H.264 Mp4 Video from HDR Images *.hdr formats files from folder using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, sh

I want to create a 10bit H.265 or H.264 Mp4 Video file  from HDR Images *.hdr formats files from folder

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24000/1001 \
-i input000001.hdr \
-i input000002.hdr \
-vf setsar=1 \
-c:v libx265 \
-crf 15 \
-preset ultrafast \
-pix_fmt yuv444p10le \
 Output_hdr_265.mp4
```

I tried this above command but I got errors like:

> [mpsub @ 000001e683b0f080] Format mpsub detected only with low score of 16, misdetection possible!
>
> Option framerate not found.

Does anyone have an idea about this query ?
please help me for this query

Comment: Which app generated these HDR images?

Comment: @Gyan Images are generated by Rendering application like unity3D , Deltagen

Comment: Fixed using by giving Input file names in side Text file
ffmpeg -framerate 24000/1001 \
-i input.txt \
-vf setsar=1 \
-c:v libx265 \
-crf 15 \
-preset ultrafast \
-pix_fmt yuv444p10le \
 Output_hdr_265.mp4